# Is the mass term of a neutral fermion zero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, majorana-fermions

[Note: my question can be a duplicate of [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/372231/majorana-mass-term), but I don't understand the answer given there.]

At various places, e.g., in the first slide of [this lecture](https://uebungen.physik.uni-heidelberg.de/c/image/f/vorlesung/20211/1346/material/Lecture-11.pdf), it is argued that for a neutral fermion $\psi$ the following term is allowed to be present in Lagrangian:

$$\frac{m}{2}(\bar{\psi^c}\psi+\bar\psi\psi^c)\mkern5mu.$$

In the Dirac representation, $\psi^c$ can be expressed as

$$\psi^c\equiv-i\gamma_2\psi^*\mkern5mu,$$

while the Dirac conjugation is defined as

$$\bar\psi\equiv\psi^\dagger\gamma_0\mkern5mu.$$

Assuming that $\psi$ is given by

$$\psi=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}\mkern5mu,$$

the $\bar\psi\psi^c$ term in the first equation becomes

$$\bar\psi\psi^c
=-i\,(a^*,b^*,c^*,d^*)\,\gamma_0\,\gamma_2\,\begin{pmatrix}a^*\\b^*\\c^*\\d^*\end{pmatrix}
=-i\,(a^*,b^*,c^*,d^*)\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&-i\\0&0&i&0\\0&-i&0&0\\i&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a^*\\b^*\\c^*\\d^*\end{pmatrix}
=(a^*,b^*,c^*,d^*)\begin{pmatrix}-d^*\\c^*\\-b^*\\a^*\end{pmatrix}
=0$$

A similar calculation shows that the $\bar{\psi^c}\psi$ term is $0$ as well.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, why are those terms introduced?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you not understand about the answer to the question you link? Explicitly, the answer there is saying your $a,b,c,d$ are Graßmann numbers and so e.g. $b^*c^* - c^*b^* \neq 0$ as they don't commute.

Comment: I did not understand where should I put those "anti-commuting Grassmann numbers". Now it is clear, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming, among others,  that $a^*d^*- d^*a^*=0$, but $a^* d^*=- d^* a^*$ because Fermi fields are Grassmann-valued and so anticommute.

Comment: Oh, that makes everything clear, thanks.